# Unusual vmware.modconfig-console output

Tags: kernel, opensuse, vmware, header-file

Upon running a batch file I created to iterate recursive directories from / trying to find the Kernel headers for `vmware-modconfig-console` running on openSUSE, when it comes across /usr/include/ it spits out the below

```
    /usr/bin/lib/vmware-tools/sbin64/vmware-modconfig-console --validate-kernel-headers
     -k 3.4.6-2.10-desktop "/usr/include" -- -l "/usr/bin/lib/vmware-tools/"

    In file included from <stdin>:2:0:
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:2:2: error: #error
    "======================================================="
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:3:2: error: #error "You should not include /usr/include
    /{linux,asm}/ header"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:4:2: error: #error "files directly for the compilation of
     kernel modules."
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:5:2: error: #error ""
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:6:2: error: #error "glibc now uses kernel header files
     from a well-defined"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:7:2: error: #error "working kernel version (as recommended
     by Linus Torvalds)"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:8:2: error: #error "These files are glibc internal and may
     not match the"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:9:2: error: #error "currently running kernel. They should
     only be"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:10:2: error: #error "included via other system header 
     files - user space"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:11:2: error: #error "programs should not directly include
     <linux/*.h> or"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:12:2: error: #error "<asm/*.h> as well."
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:13:2: error: #error ""
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:14:2: error: #error "Since Linux 2.6, the kernel module
     build process has been"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:15:2: error: #error "updated such that users building
     modules should not typically"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:16:2: error: #error "need to specify additional include 
     directories at all."
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:17:2: error: #error ""
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:18:2: error: #error "To build kernel modules, ensure you
     have the build environment "
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:19:2: error: #error "available either via the kernel-devel
     and kernel-<flavor>-devel "
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:20:2: error: #error "packages or a properly configured
     kernel source tree."
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:21:2: error: #error ""
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:22:2: error: #error "Then, modules can be built using:"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:23:2: error: #error "make -C <path> M=/home/abuild/
     rpmbuild/BUILD/linux-glibc-devel-3.4"
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:24:2: error: #error ""
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:25:2: error: #error "For the currently running kernel
     there will be a symbolic "
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:26:2: error: #error "link pointing to the build 
     environment located at "
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:27:2: error: #error "/lib/modules/2.6.37.6-0.11-xen/build
     for use as <path>."
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:28:2: error: #error ""
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:29:2: error: #error "If you are seeing this message, your
     environment is "
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:30:2: error: #error "not configured properly. "
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:31:2: error: #error ""
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:32:2: error: #error "Please adjust the Makefile
     accordingly."
    /usr/include/linux/version.h:33:2: error: #error
    "======================================================="
```

This looks to be an almost exact copy of the contents of /usr/include/linux/version.h, but what I cant't work out is why this one subdirectory is making the vmware-modconfig-console tool echo the contents of a file in a subdirectory to stdout??